# Why is Cocoa's [NSDate distantPast] not equal to the same date initialised from a string?

Tags: cocoa, date

If this code is executed in an empty Cocoa app:

```
NSLog([[NSDate distantPast] isEqualToDate:[NSDate dateWithString:[[NSDate distantPast] description]]] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

I get `NO` as the result.

Given how long NSDate has been around I wouldn't expect it to be a bug, but it looks a little odd because `[NSDate dateWithString:@"0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"]` actually returns `0001-01-03 00:00:00 +0000`.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is -[NSDate dateWithString:]. And it is deprecated as of 10.7.

```
@interface NSDate (NSCalendarDateExtras)
/*    DEPRECATED DEPRECATED DEPRECATED
 *    These methods are deprecated.
 *    Use NSCalendar for calendrical calculations.
 *    Use NSDateFormatter for date<->string conversions.
 */
...
+ (id)dateWithString:(NSString *)aString;
...
@end
```

This method has always been problematic and never recommended for date parsing. NSDateFormatter allows better control over parsing.